# Count number of elements satisfied with By.css()

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am doing simple test:

```
 <span *ngFor="let p of products" class="a">{{p.name}}</span>
```

There are 3 products, leading to creation of 3 span elements. How can I get that count when using By.css():

```
  it(":", () => {
    let de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".a"));
    fixture.detectChanges();
     //  let el = de.nativeElement;
    expect('number of span elements created').toEqual(component.products.legnth);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `fixture.debugElement.queryAll` instead of `fixture.debugElement.query`.
So test will looks like

```
 it(":", () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const spans = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css(".a"));
    const spansLength = spans.length;
    expect(spansLength).toEqual(component.products.legnth);
  });
```

Description of queryAll method can be found [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#debugelement-1)